# How do I implement this image view in an async task?

Tags: android, asynchronous, imageview

I have an url passed to an activity and I am trying to show the image from the url full screen, however it throws a main network thread exception.

From what I can find I believe I have to put the method in an async task however I cannot seem to make sense of it at all. So how would I put this method in an async task?

FullScreenImageView.java

```
public class FullscreenImageView extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("SelectedImageURL");



    try {
        ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());
        i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: put `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` into doInBackground return Bitmap and in onPostExecute set this bitmap to image

Comment: http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-load-image-from-internet.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be  something like this.
In the `doInBackground` you get the image, and in the `onPostExecute` you set it

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>  {
     @Override
     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
          Bitmap bitmap = null; 
          try {
              bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(urls[0]).getContent());
          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return bitmap;
     }
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     }
 }
```

Then, you call it inside your `onCreate` method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("SelectedImageURL");
    new DownloadFilesTask ().execute(url); 
}
```

Comment: does this all go within the oncreate method?

Comment: unfortunately this is showing "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference" when i click

Comment: when you click what ?

Comment: From that error I can assume that something is missing in your activity, causing the ImageView to be null. 
I can't see a setContentView in your code, so maybe that is whats missing.

Answer (score 0):

Put your network task inside `doInBackground()` method of AsyncTask as follow:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

try {
        //ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);Put this line in onPreExecute() method
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());
       // i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);//and this one on postExecute() method
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: @Selvin Please have a look and consider voting as well if you like :-)

Comment: @Selvin sorry but couldn't understand the reason

Comment: @SpiderMan this is life, things go up, and things go down. <3

Answer (score 0):

Using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) after initializing `yourImageView` with findViewById();

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(yourImageView)
```